# Swift 3 CollectionView scaling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I recently implemented a collection view in a app, the only problem I'm experiencing is that the collection view goes from 2 column to 1 column on smaller devices with a lot of padding on both sides

heres on a display smaller then a iPhone 6:
[image]

and heres how it looks on a display bigger or equal to a iPhone 6:
[image]

I did try several method where if the display width was smaller then a certain number it would scale up the cells, but it failed to work out because the cells where indeed scaled up but where not centered and over-lapping themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to calculate the cell width.Try this code.

```
class YourClass: UIViewController {
        //MARK:-Outlets
        @IBOutlet weak var yourCollectionView: UICollectionView!

        //Mark:-Variables
        var cellWidth:CGFloat = 0
        var cellHeight:CGFloat = 0
        var spacing:CGFloat = 12
        var numberOfColumn:CGFloat = 2


        //MARK:-LifeCycle
        override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
            super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

            yourCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: spacing, left: spacing, bottom: spacing, right: spacing)

            if let flowLayout = yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout{
                cellWidth = (yourCollectionView.frame.width  - (numberOfColumn + 1)*spacing)/numberOfColumn
               cellHeight = cellWidth //yourCellHeight = cellWidth if u want square cell
                flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = spacing
                flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = spacing
            }
        }

     extension YourClass:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
            func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
                return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight)
            }
    }
```

Comment: can you explain for collection view in one line and change the height of cells ? please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate your sizes depending on the phone size - if two cell's width are larger then screen size ( including all offsets between them ) they will layout as in the first picture.

You have two options:
One is to deal with sizes and rescale cells according to device size
Two leave it as is - Make small changes for iphone6/6s/7.

If you opt out for first one, you will need to set up constraint for these sizes - aspect ratio or center horizontally ( which could crop the image a little ).

For changing sizes dynamically, take a look at:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout

More specific: 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1617708-collectionview

Comment: nothing changes when I try to change the size dynamically :/

Comment: Have you included offsets from sides and distance between cells ? You can check easily but setting width to 20 or something like that

Comment: @NickCatib Please provide him some code rather than links.